# Single Front-end for multiple SSRS/SQL instances

Tags: reporting-services, farm-solution

We have 3 plants all interconnected with high speed WAN. Each plant has it's own SQL server (for it's own applications), but people from all three plants need to run reports on each server.  If we host reports locally at each site and point to remote DB's, performance is terrible. IF we logon to SSRS remotely, performance is acceptable as only the screen rendering is across the WAN link, but then employees have to go to three URL's

The most heavily used SSRS server (plant A) has a front-end that is part of 3rd party's product. It has good user access control and lets us control access at the report level. From what I understand, the native SSRS web UI can only control access at the folder level, so we'd end up with huge set of folders to get correct level of access control granularity.

I did think about building my own BI front end. This would present available reports to a user based on a UserID/EmployeeID tuple in a custom table. When the user clicks a report it would simply navigate to the relevant URL (at any site - e.g. http://PlantB.com/reports/report1) (had to put on the .com to satisfy editor.

This did get me thinking: does anyone know of a commercial product that gives a single front end to a farm of SSRS servers. It's nothing to do with load balancing, just a single UI to control access to, and provide a single launchpad for users. So when UserA logs in, they see reports that they are allowed to run. If they are at Plant A and running a report located at plant B, it would simple point to http://PlantB.com/reports/report1

I googled it a bit, but didn't turn up anything

Regards

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I think SharePoint would do the job.  You could link to Report Manager reports or folders, add Web Parts to show reports in a SharePoint page, or fully integrate a new SSRS instance with SharePoint.